# "Java for Windows missing" dialogue while installing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, environment-variables

I tried installing Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3) for 64 bit. The installer keeps redirecting me to a page that tells me to install a Java JRE/IDE (http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/?vm=1_1_7_0_64_0&pn=Eclipse%20Installer&pu=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer&pi=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/jre/128x128.png), even though I've installed the JRE(1.8.0, for 64 bit) and set the paths correctly.[The Environment variables dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7e17.png)

Is it something wrong with the path? Or do I have to download the IDE too? 
P.S. I'm sort of a noobie here, so I can't directly insert the image, sorry.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your link says:

> or a Java Development Kit (JDK) if you plan to do Java development:

So i would install a JDK instead of a JRE.

Also the value of `PATH` environment variable should start with:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin; ...
```

Comment: Bingo!  Got it! I had missed the backslash before bin! Thanks bud.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the "64 bit" rather than the "86 bit", worked for me